# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')"

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a menu in `thymleaf` and i have a login - logout button inside it.
Here is the complete page of this menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" th:fragment="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RentIt Company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')}">
              <a href="/signin" th:href="@{/signin}">Sign in</a>
            </li>
            <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
              <a href="/logout" th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when i run, it complains with:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')"
```

It seems that, it does not recognize the `isAuthenticated` method, so how can i fix it?

Comment: @Ali Dehghani ...........

Comment: please share spring xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the dependencies in you project, see below the piece of code in the build.gradle (I'm using gradle, adapt to your build system if different):

```
dependencies {
    // your dependencies ...
    compile "org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.1.RELEASE"
    compile "org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.1.RELEASE"
}
```

And also is necessary add a Spring Security extension to Thymeleaf in your configuration as follow:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HomeController.class)
public class ServletContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect(););
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(defaultTemplateResolver(applicationContext));
        return templateEngine;
    }
    // other @Bean configurations ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change version of org.thymeleaf.extras as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
```

It will solve your problem

Comment: Are you sure this is still relevant? This problem is nearly two years old